# How to handle pop up and cookies in selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, cookies

I have a problem while scraping  [MorningStar website](https://www.morningstar.it/it/) with Chrome Selenium. Everytime I get to the webpage, it shows a pop up that ask me if I'm an individual investor or not (basically are cookies). I can easily handle and close it locating and clicking the html element. But after I do a search in the website, the pop up shows again. Why if I run chrome normally this popup never shows (not even at the beginning), while if I use the webdriver it always shows? It's like the webdriver doesn't take all the cookies and setting from the original Chrome.

[image: This is the pop up shown]

On the upper-right corner there's also selected "save the choices for 90 days." by default. How can I handle it? Is there a way to import all the cookies from chrome to selenium webdriver?

Answer (score 0):

try this ..

```
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=chrome-data")
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe',options=chrome_options)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Unluckily not. Same problem.